# Why is it useful to use epsilon-delta to prove theorems and propositions?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

This might be a weird question, but i am trying to understand how mathematical proofs work and why is that the epsilon-delta is so useful in terms of proving, as the title say, theorems or propositions. I am getting started in mathematics and i am really excited to understand these kind of proofs.

Comment: Usually you are dealing with some limiting procedure when dealing with $\epsilon,\delta$-calculations. This occurs when you cannot look at a specific point or number, but instead need to look nearby. Using an $\epsilon,\delta$ argument allows one to make systematic and rigorous what it means to be "nearby".

Comment: Limit is defined in $\epsilon$-$\delta$-formalism. Therefore at least some basic theorems regarding limits need to be proved in $\epsilon$-$\delta$-formalism. Looking at some concrete cases also helps understanding how the formalism and more abstract cases work.